# Adding namespace in urls causes error that should not even be there

Tags: python, django

I have a very strange problem I really don't understand.

I am using `django-registragion-redux` and an almost unchanged `login.html` template provided by the package.

My `urls.py` file looks like so:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include('main_site.urls', namespace='main'), name='main'),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls))
]
```

The template `templates/registration/login.html` contains two relevant lines, along with filler:

```
<p>{% trans "Not a member?" %} <a href="{% url 'registration_register' %}">{% trans "Register now!" %}</a>.</p>
<p>{% trans "Forgot your password?" %} <a href="{% url 'auth_password_reset' %}">{% trans "Reset it" %}</a>.</p>
```

Using these settings, everything works perfectly fine. I go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/ and the basic site is there, and the links are set correctly.

However, I want to have a cleaner code and was advised to use namespaces. OK, no problem. I change my urls to

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include('main_site.urls', namespace='main'), name='main'),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls', namespace='accounts')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls))
]
```

and I change my template to

```
<p>{% trans "Not a member?" %} <a href="{% url 'accounts:registration_register' %}">{% trans "Register now!" %}</a>.</p>
<p>{% trans "Forgot your password?" %} <a href="{% url 'accounts:auth_password_reset' %}">{% trans "Reset it" %}</a>.</p>
```

Now, when I open the page http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/, I get the following error message:

```
NoReverseMatch at /accounts/login/
Reverse for 'auth_password_reset_done' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/
Django Version: 1.8.3
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'auth_password_reset_done' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

Now this is strange for two reasons:

1. The namespacing obviously works. The `accounts:registration_register` tag gets reversed nicely. If I only keep the second paragraph in the file, there is no error.
2. The error states that the reverse for `auth_password_reset_done` cannot be found, but **there is no mention** of `auth_password_reset_done` in the template! The error actually occurs trying to reverse `auth_password_reset`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `django-registration-redux` reverses some URLs in [registration/auth_urls](https://github.com/macropin/django-registration/blob/4e4b25d63060d00ab7f6a1c3bac2985641c04a0b/registration/auth_urls.py#L52). As no namespace is used, reversing the URL fails.

There are two possible workarounds:

- instead of including the `urls.py` (and implicitely `auth_urls.py`) from `django-registration-redux`, copy them into your project and fix the calls to `reverse_lazy`
- fork `django-registration-redux`, fix the issue and submit a pull request

Comment: Wow, neither of those options looks fun. Thanks for the help anyway.